# KOWL Kafka Connect yaml configuration - has anyone managed to get it right?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm getting this error: {"level":"fatal","msg":"failed to load config","error":"failed to unmarshal YAML config into config struct: 1 error(s) decoding:\n\n* '' has invalid keys: connect"}

with the folowing yaml:

kafka:
brokers:
- 192.168.12.12:9092
schemaRegistry:
enabled: true
urls:
- "http://192.168.12.12:8081"
connect:
enabled: true
clusters:

- name: xy
  url: "http://192.168.12.12:8091"
  tls:
  enabled: false
  username: 1
  password: 1
- name: xya
  url: http://192.168.12.12:8092

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrade your image back to v1.5.0.
Seems that there's a mistake in master recently.

You could find all the images [here](https://quay.io/repository/cloudhut/kowl?tab=tags)